# How would a biolectrical plant work?

Tags: science-based, biology, near-future, electricity, genetic-engineering

I was wondering...

If only we could make a GMO plant that could produce electricty thanks to bioelectricty.

How could that be done, how could it produce a lot of energy,

Also, how could we harvest and take the electricty the plant produced?

Thank you for your contribution...

Comment: Plants accumulate energy from sunlight by photosynthesis, with an efficiency of a few percent. Plain cheap ordinary photovoltaic panels make electricity from sunlight with an efficiency of 20% or more, one order of magnitude better. And they work in deserts without any need for irrigation, so that they don't compete with agriculture.

Comment: Tons of potatoes...

Answer (score 1):

An algae that produces a charge grown in thin sheets over a conductive polymer, basically it's a bio-solar panel. I'd look at the charge structures in the [Electric Eel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_eel), you might need a double layer of two different GMOs to mimic the structure properly. It would build charge using [photosynthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosynthesis) as a basic energy source and converting it directly into electricity which would flow through the polymer substrate and into the grid.

Answer (score 0):

You could put your GMO plants into some form of conductive liquid, in which the electric charge produced by the plants would be gathered and transformed into an electric current by applying an electric potential difference. Then use wires to direct the electricity wherever you want.